# Filter an array of products by number months

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter

I am doing a project in vue and I am trying to filter from a list of products that come in a json that has an array of objects within an array. I have a selector with different months to be able to filter by the number of months that each of the products has and only show the products that contain those months.

```
[
  {
    "active": true,
    "installment": [
      [
        {
          "product": "Ipad",
          "months": 12,
          "installment": 63.94
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "product": "Ipad",
          "months": 6,
          "installment": 63.94
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "active": true,
    "installment": [
      [
        {
          "product": "Iphone",
          "months": 12,
          "installment": 63.94
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "product": "Iphone",
          "months": 6,
          "installment": 63.94
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "active": true,
    "installment": [
      [
        {
          "product": "Mac",
          "months": 18,
          "installment": 63.94
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

This would be the json that if in the month selector I select 12 months I would like to obtain

```
[
  {
    "active": true,
    "installment": [
      [
        {
          "product": "Ipad",
          "months": 12,
          "installment": 63.94
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "active": true,
    "installment": [
      [
        {
          "product": "Iphone",
          "months": 12,
          "installment": 63.94
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure there is a more elegant way but here is one way to do it:

```js
var arr = [
  {
    "active": true,
    "installment": [
      [
        {
          "product": "Ipad",
          "months": 12,
          "installment": 63.94
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "product": "Ipad",
          "months": 6,
          "installment": 63.94
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "active": true,
    "installment": [
      [
        {
          "product": "Iphone",
          "months": 12,
          "installment": 63.94
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "product": "Iphone",
          "months": 6,
          "installment": 63.94
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "active": true,
    "installment": [
      [
        {
          "product": "Mac",
          "months": 18,
          "installment": 63.94
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
]

var result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (curr.installment.flat().some(i => i.months == 12)) {
    acc.push({
      ...curr,
      installment: [curr.installment.flat().filter(i => i.months == 12)]
    })
  }

  return acc
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: but to put the active and the installment I have to do a push, is there any way to have that without doing a push? because there it has more things besides active and installment

Comment: Hi @JesúsDel, I updated my answer so only the installment property gets filtered and all other properties would remain.  Still needs`push` though since this method requires creating a new `result` array.